# What kind of micro-processor / micro-controller are able to run Blockchain light client?

Tags: blockchain, clients, iot

Is there any kind of `micro-processor` / `micro-controller` that can run **Blockchain light client**?

An example can be **Samsung ARTIK**: https://www.artik.io

However, it's too **big**. Is there any other similar but **smaller** micro-controller that is able to run Blockchain light client?

**P.S. 1 :** For example, I do not know `NODEMCU` and `ESP8266` are a good choice for this purpose? (example: https://hackaday.com/2018/05/02/using-blockchain-explorer-apis-on-nodemcu/)

**P.S. 2 :** The projects seem run a blockchain client on a micro-controller:

(1) [EthEmbedded](http://ethembedded.com/) 
(2) [Elkrem](https://techcrunch.com/2018/08/21/elkrem-is-a-blockchain-dev-board-for-tinkerers/?guccounter=1)
(3) [EthArmbian](https://github.com/diglos/userpatches#etharmbian)

**P.S. 3 :**  And also can we consider Raspberry PI as a `micro-rocessor` / `micro-controller`? Since apparently, it's possible to install Ethereum Blockchain on it. (more information: https://ethraspbian.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Check for raspbery pi, raspnode,  [link here](http://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html) . Memory storage for raspbery pi could be on an MicroSD card. Also, for ARM processors, there is a build  [EthEmbedded](http://ethembedded.com/) .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your request concerning hardware specs but eg status.im has a light client integrated in their mobile application.

It requires a couple 100mb in storage, some ram but especially bandwith.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems interesting as well: https://techcrunch.com/2018/08/21/elkrem-is-a-blockchain-dev-board-for-tinkerers/